# Loading all modules recursivly from subfolders in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have following file structure

```
./AppFolder
    __init__.py
    main.py
    ./plugin
         __init__.py
         ./simple_plugin_1
             __init__.py
             simple_plugin_1.py
         ./simple_plugin_2
             __init__.py
             simple_plugin_2.py
```

and i want to load all plugin modules recursively into main.py. So can I use `__init__.py` in AppFolder as following?

```
import os
import glob
__all__ = [ os.path.basename(f)[:-3] for f in glob.glob(os.path.dirname(__file__)+"/plugin/*/*.py")]
```

Or is there are other techniques?

Comment: I think it's a very good option but i would add a check for `startswith('_')` unless you want to load all the `__init__.py` files.

Comment: How? Can you give a hint? Or if you have answer can you publish it?

Comment: @Phoneix you are iterating on f (file name) so something like `if not os.path.basename(f).startswith('__')`, again it's not a must, your code is fine as it is.

Answer (score 1):

I have this bit of code that I use for this purpose, just use this as your top level `__init__.py`:

```
import pkgutil

__all__ = []
for loader, module_name, is_pkg in pkgutil.walk_packages(__path__):
    module = loader.find_module(module_name).load_module(module_name)
    exec('%s = module' % module_name)
    __all__.append(module_name)
```

Basically same idea as what you have, but just using `pkgutil.walk_packages` to find all the modules instead of a file glob.